# WooCommerce display price on add to cart button for external products on product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to add the price to the add to cart button on the product details page for external products

[£100 Buy Now] instead of [But Now]

hoping the achieve a similar modification to the one asked question here:
[WooCommerce display price on add to cart button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997599/woocommerce-display-price-on-add-to-cart-button)

**single-product/add-to-cart/external.php template**

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
<p class="cart">
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_url ); ?>" rel="nofollow" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">
    <?php echo $button_text; ?>
  </a>
</p>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
```

Just can't figure out where to included the code below to pull in the price

```
<?php if ( $price_html = $product->get_price_html() ) : ?>
    <span class="price"><?php echo $price_html; ?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your external.php file with the following code.

```
<?php
/**
 * External product add to cart
  *
  * @author         WooThemes
  * @package    WooCommerce/Templates
  * @version     2.1.0
  */

 if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
 }

 global $product;
 ?>

 <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

  <p class="cart">
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product_url ); ?>" rel="nofollow" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
<?php echo $button_text; ?>
</a>
</p>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>
```