# Change "add to cart" text to the price of the product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change the text of my "add-to-cart" button in woocommerce to the current price of that product. With the code below I can change the text. This works fine.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text');
function woo_custom_cart_button_text($button_text) {
$button_text -> 'hello!';
return __($button_text, 'woocommerce' );
}
```

But now I want to change that text in the price of the product. I've tried the following code, replacing line 3 with:

```
$button_text->get_price_html();
```

But that gives me an error. Any idea's how to solve this problem?

Comment: UPDATE 

`function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text($button_text) { $button_text -> 'hello!';
return __($button_text, 'woocommerce' );
}`
solved the error, but now there is no text visible in the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
        $button_text = get_price_html();
        return __( $button_text, 'woocommerce' );

}
```

You may need to assign $button_text with the assignment opperator (=).

Or...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text' );    // 2.1 +

function woo_custom_cart_button_text() {
        global $post;
        $product = get_product( $post->ID );
        $button_text = $product->get_price_html();
        return __( $button_text, 'woocommerce' );

}
```

Comment: `get_price_html()` is not a function. It is a class method that must operate on an object, ex: `$product->get_price_html()`. So the second block is closer, though I discovered that it results in some crazy button text. The product object is available in the filter and can be passed by setting the number of accepted args to 2. Lastly, `__( $button_text, 'woocommerce' );` is incorrect since `$button_text` is now a dynamic variable and can't be translated.

Comment: what type of products are you trying to change because there is an answer here for changing external products only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947203/woocommerce-display-price-on-add-to-cart-button-for-external-products-on-product

Comment: The OP didn't say. Overriding templates is always possible, but you run into fewer problems updating WC if you use hooks/filters. I was just pointing out the problems with your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `$product` to your function, by setting the number of accepted arguments to 2 in [`apply_filters()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'woo_custom_cart_button_text', 10, 2);
function woo_custom_cart_button_text($button_text, $product) {
    return $product->get_price_html();
}
```

However, this results in a problem because the template that displays the link is using `esc_html()` to wrap the resulting text which causes this hot mess (because the price html has html tags in it)

[image: all the spans]

Therefore, I think it might be better to filter the link itself:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'woo_custom_cart_button_link', 10, 2);
function woo_custom_cart_button_link($button_text, $product) {
    return sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->id ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        $product->get_price_html()
    );
}
```