# Fatal error:Call to a member function add_to_cart_url() on a non-object in wp-content/themes/vantage/functions.php on line 398

Tags: php, wordpress

So i wanted to display the price of my product in Add to cart button and followed this instruction [WooCommerce display price on add to cart button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997599/woocommerce-display-price-on-add-to-cart-button)

when i refreshed the page i saw that error and i am really sad now.
and i dont understand what that EDIT in the answer mean. Then i deleted the code that i took from the tutorial but still get error.

i am really desperate , the fatal error tells that the error is on line 398 , but there are only 397 lines , maybe i deleted some curly bracket?

and i tried to find the problem with help of debugger and i get another error
https:// ideone.com / ug95Gc
i think that it is better that i dont post almost 400 lines of code here

so debuggers show that the problem is here

```
    if( file_exists( get_template_directory() . '/premium/functions.php' ) ){
    include get_template_directory() . '/premium/functions.php';
}
else {
    include get_template_directory() . '/upgrade/upgrade.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i basically replaced my functions.php and the problem was in the solution that was in the WooCommerce display price on add to cart button , i deleted thouse lines of code and now everything is smooth.