# Woocommerce - How to display the price in the ADD-TO-CART button?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've tried every solution out there (not that there are many), but I still can't figure out how to show the price inside the ADD TO CART button.
This doesn't work --> [WooCommerce display price on add to cart button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997599/woocommerce-display-price-on-add-to-cart-button)

**The final text should be "ADD TO CART - JUST $price"**.

Is there any way to do this? I don't mind if it is from the functions.php or directly in the add-to-cart.php

Any help would be appreciated.