# Displaying price including add-ons in "Add-to-cart"-button in single product view

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to show the price of the product in the single product view in the button. I tried this solution [WooCommerce display price on add to cart button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997599/woocommerce-display-price-on-add-to-cart-button) - but I have product-add-ons (with the plug-in from YITH).

The price is shown in the table above the button, so it is calculated. But how do I get it, I can't find it in the source code, to move it into the button (see picture).

I tried now several solutions, but sadly nothing works. Can anybody give me a hint in the right direction? Sorry, I am a beginner at this, but I'm trying.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your single product page link?

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://seitenkreativ.com/bestellservice24shop1/produkt/pizza-marinara/

Comment: I posted my answer

Answer (score 2):

I used `jquery` to read the `total amount` value and then changed the button's `text`.

```js
var myTotalPrice = $(".yith_wapo_group_final_total .price").text()
$("button.single_add_to_cart_button").text(myTotalPrice)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="yith_wapo_group_total
        yith_wapo_keep_show" data-product-price="7.2" data-product-id="63">
        <table>
            <tbody><tr class="ywapo_tr_product_base_price">
                <td data-nosnippet="">Product price</td>
                <td data-nosnippet=""><div class="yith_wapo_group_product_price_total"><span class="price amount">€&nbsp;7,20</span></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ywapo_tr_additional_options">
                <td data-nosnippet="">Add-Ons Total:</td>
                <td data-nosnippet=""><div class="yith_wapo_group_option_total"><span class="price amount">€&nbsp;2,40</span></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="ywapo_tr_order_totals">
                <td data-nosnippet="">Gesamtsumme:</td>
                <td data-nosnippet=""><div class="yith_wapo_group_final_total"><span class="price amount">€&nbsp;9,60</span></div></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>

<button type="submit" name="add-to-cart" value="63" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt">In den Warenkorb</button>
```

The easiest way to insert this JS to your theme is to use [Code Snippets](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/) plugin. There is an example JS snippet there. Just copy/paste the 2 line JS code here into that example snippet.

Make sure you inject this `snippet` into the `footer` section of your theme.

**EDIT: Please try this code to get the latest price value on the page when it is changed.**

```
var priceElement = $(".yith_wapo_group_final_total .price")
$(priceElement).change(function(){
  var myTotalPrice = priceElement.text()
  $("button.single_add_to_cart_button").text(myTotalPrice)
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check it and let you know!

Comment: So, I tried it now. I put the following code on the very bottom of the page:
`jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
 // when opening the page
 var myTotalPrice = $(".yith_wapo_group_final_total .price").text();
 $("button.single_add_to_cart_button").text('In den Warenkorb: ' + myTotalPrice); 
 
 // on change of the form
 $(".cart :input").change(function() {
  var myTotalPrice = $(".yith_wapo_group_final_total .price").text();
  $("button.single_add_to_cart_button").text('In den Warenkorb: ' + myTotalPrice);
 });
});`
It basically works, but always shows the value of 1 click before

Comment: @webwurm Sorry for my late reply, I suggested an updated code that should take care of the price changes. Please see the edit in my answer